# How to re-render Flatlist in React Native using componentWillRecieveProps?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux

```
    UNSAFE_componentWillMount(){
        this.props.EmployeeFetch();
    }

    renderRow(employee){
        return <ListItem employee={employee}/>;
    }
render(){
    return(
        <FlatList style={{flex:1,height:100}} 
        data = {this.props.employees}
        />
    );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps=state=>{
    const employees = _.map(state.employees,(val,uid)=>{
        return {...val,uid};
    });
    return {employees};
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {EmployeeFetch})(EmployeeList);
```

Here I am fetching data from firebase. At first it came null and after some time data came. So, how will I re-render the new data using the Flatlist and componentWillRecieveProps()?

Comment: which database u are using firestore or realtime database

Comment: real-time data base

Comment: also using react-redux to manage the state.

Answer (score 0):

you should use 2 return function.

1 which return loading (activity indicator)

2 which return data if data exists in any state.

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isLoading: true};
    }
  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading){
          return( 
            <View> 
              <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0c9"/>
            </View>
    )}
    return(
        <FlatList style={{flex:1,height:100}} 
        data = {this.props.employees}
        />
    );

const mapStateToProps=state=>{
    const employees = _.map(state.employees,(val,uid)=>{
        return {...val,uid};
    });
    if(employees){
         this.state.isLoading = false;
    }

    return {employees};
}
```

note: do not forget to import react components 
and also if you are using react navigation then try to use to navigation events for data fetch api rather than using UNSAFE_componentWillMount() or find some other solution.

Comment: I  m not using state but redux

Answer (score 0):

So `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated, you should use `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

You can use it like this with your example:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
   const { employees } = this.props;
   return employees;
}
```

Then in your `render`:

```
render() {
   const { employees } = this.props;

   // then use map(employees) 
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate using my code. I am new to RN

Comment: @BestOFBest please update your post with your entire component so I can see the props etc.